# scrapy xpath : selector with many <tr> <td>

Tags: xpath, scrapy

Hello I want to ask a question

I scrape a website with xpath ,and the result is like this:

```
[u'<tr>\r\n                    
    <td>address1</td>\r\n                    
    <td>phone1</td>\r\n                    
    <td>map1</td>\r\n                  
  </tr>',
 u'<tr>\r\n
    <td>address1</td>\r\n                
    <td>telephone1</td>\r\n             
    <td>map1</td>\r\n
  </tr>'...
u'<tr>\r\n
    <td>address100</td>\r\n                
    <td>telephone100</td>\r\n             
    <td>map100</td>\r\n
  </tr>']
```

now I need to use xpath to analyze this results again.
I want to save the first  to address,the second  to telephone,and the last one to map
But I can't get it.

Please guide me.Thank you!

Here is code,it's wrong. it will catch another thing.

```
store =   sel.xpath("")
for s in store:     
    address = s.xpath("//tr/td[1]/text()").extract()
    tel = s.xpath("//tr/td[2]/text()").extract()
    map = s.xpath("//tr/td[3]/text()").extract()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in [scrappy documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths) to work with relative XPaths you have to use `.//` notation to extract the elements relative to the previous XPath, if not you're getting again all elements from the whole document. You can see this sample in the scrappy documentation that I referenced above:

> For example, suppose you want to extract all `<p>` elements inside `<div>` elements. First, you would get all `<div>` elements:
>
> `divs = response.xpath('//div')`
>
> At first, you may be tempted to use the following approach, which is wrong, as it actually extracts all `<p>` elements from the document, not only those inside `<div>` elements:
>
> `for p in divs.xpath('//p'):`  # this is wrong - gets all `<p>` from the whole document
>
> This is the proper way to do it (note the dot prefixing the `.//p` XPath):
>
> `for p in divs.xpath('.//p'):`  # extracts all `<p>` inside

So I think in your case you code must be something like:

```
for s in store:     
    address = s.xpath(".//tr/td[1]/text()").extract()
    tel = s.xpath(".//tr/td[2]/text()").extract()
    map = s.xpath(".//tr/td[3]/text()").extract()
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks ! You are right. But I have a question.I use ````s.xpath(".//td[1]/text()").extract()[0]```` and It works.But ````s.xpath(".//tr/td[1]/text()").extract()```` not work. Doyou know Why?

Comment: You're welcome `:)`. I'm not sure but this `s.xpath(".//tr/td[1]/text()").extract()` doesn't work because probably `s` element is already inside `<tr>` node so you don't need to reference this node again.